# non-existence of an infinite composition of functions

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, function-and-relation-composition

I'm quite naive in math, and this question is to ask suggestions in how to pose a problem or to know if I'm just saying nonsense.

I have a map $\phi:\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^m$, for some $n,m\in\mathbb N_{>0}$, that is as much regular as needed. Given a $x\in\mathbb R^n$, I can define the mapping $\phi_x:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^m$ as $\phi_x(\cdot) = \phi(x,\cdot)$.

I was trying to falsify a condition, that I will call $C$. Thus I assumed $C$ to hold, and at a certain point I found that $C$ implies the following 
$$
 c=\Big(\phi_a\circ\phi_a\circ\phi_a\circ\cdots\Big)(b)\qquad\qquad(1)
$$
with $a\in\mathbb R^n$ and $b,c\in\mathbb R^m$ some given points and with the object "$\phi_a\circ\phi_a\circ\phi_a\circ\cdots$" that is to be interpreted as the infinite compositions of the map $\phi_a$.

Now, I think that I could neither write (1) as far as I don't know that "$\phi_a\circ\phi_a\circ\phi_a\circ\cdots$" makes sense, and that's the point. I actually do not want (1) to make sense, since if (1) does not, that would imply that $C$ cannot hold (by the way, am I correct in saying so?). Thus essentially my preliminary strategy is to find sufficient conditions on $\phi_a$ under which (1) does not make sense.

As I want to study the "non-existence" (just to say) properties of "$\phi_a\circ\phi_a\circ\phi_a\circ\cdots$", it seems to me fair to start working with something I can define. For instance, given $k\in\mathbb N$, by letting
$$
\Phi_a^k := \underbrace{\phi_a\circ\cdots\circ \phi_a}_{k\;times}
$$
I can try to study something like the existence of $\lim_{k\to\infty}\Phi_a^k$, with $\lim$ that I think is to be intended as a pontwise limit.

I found many references on sufficient conditions for the existence of limits of the kind of $\lim_{k\to\infty}\Phi_a^k$, however I did not find anything useful on the non-existence of such objects (for instance conditions under which the sequence of $\Phi_a^k$ does not converge to any function).

I'm also interested in results saying that if $\lim_{k\to\infty}\Phi^k_a$ exists or if (1) holds then **necessarily** $\phi_a$ must have some given properties ( thus necessary conditions rather than sufficient) or something characterising the values of $(b,c)$ for which (1) holds, or don't).

Do you have any hint?
thanks.

Comment: When you say that condition $C$ implies the condition, do you mean that it implies that $c = \lim_{k \to \infty} \phi_a^k(b)$ (where the superscript means composition $k$ times)?

Comment: yes. Essentially $C$ implies that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\phi_a^k$ is well-defined and that $c=\lim_{k\to\infty}\phi_a^k(b)$.

Comment: So the question is, assuming that $f$ is a smooth function and and $c = \lim_{k \to + \infty} f^k(b)$, what can be said about $f$, $b$ and $c$? For one thing, since $f$ is continuous, this implies that $f(c) = c$.

Comment: thanks. is the fixed-point theorem saying that, right?

Comment: This is the same as saying that the recursive sequence $x_k$ defined by $x_0 = b$ and $x_{k+1}= f(x_k)$ tends to $c$. If that's true, then since $x_k \to c$ and $f$ is continuous, we have $x_{k+1} = f(x_k) \to f(c)$, so $f(c) = c$. There are no fancy theorems here.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot.

Comment: In the single-variable case, if $f$ is continuously differentiable and the sequence $x_k$ never takes the exact value $c$, the condition also implies that $|f'(c)| \leq 1$. Otherwise we'd have $|x_{k+1} - c| \geq |x_k - c|$ for all large enough values of $k$, which is absurd.

Comment: thanks for your help. Let's fix $c=b=0$. The main question is, given $f$ smooth, what conditions prevent $\{f^k\}_{k=1}^{N}$ to converge pointwise to a function as $N\to\infty$? The problem maps naturally to the stability properties of the difference equation $x_{k+1} = f(x_k)$.In fact if for some $x_0$ the corresponding sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ diverges then $\lim_{k\to\infty} f^k$ is not defined in $x_0$ right?

Comment: to give more structure I will add a detail: If $F:=\lim_{k\to\infty}f^k$ exists, then $C$ also implies that the differential equation $\dot x = F(x)$ ($\dot x$ here denotes the time derivative) admits one and only one complete solution for each initial condition $x_0$ and the corresponding trajectory $x(t)$ is such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)=0$.

Comment: If $c = b = 0$, then the sequence $f^k(b)$ is constant. Your last statement in the first comment is correct. I'm not sure how $C$ can imply what you say and also imply that $F$ doesn't exist. Anyway, I'm not going to be able to help you with the differential equation part.